# How to handle back browser button problem using spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How to handle back browser button problem using spring?.

In my application user login properly and when user click on back button page state is not maintained. So do i maintain the page state even the user click on back button / forward button

Thanks

Comment: You can do it easily using interceptions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420941/how-handle-browser-back-button-in-spring-mvc/31217043#31217043

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the pages are been requested from the browser cache. You'll need to disable the client-side caching of the pages in question. You can do this by creating a `Filter` which listens on an `url-pattern` of the pages you'd like to disable the cache for, such as `*.jsp`. Do the following in the `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpServletResponse httpres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpres.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
httpres.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
httpres.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

This way, the client side application will be instructed to **not** cache the requests matching the `url-pattern` of this filter. Pressing the back button would then force a *real* request from the server, with the proposed fresh data. To retain certain server-side data between the requests, you'll need to grab the session scope or use GET requests only.

Oh, don't forget to clear the browser cache first after implementing and before testing ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use Spring Web Flow

[I recommend this link to check about Spring web flow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow)

Answer (score 0):

Configure an interceptor inside Servlet Context as this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/*"/>
        <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Note: Don't forget to remove your browser cache while testing your application.