# After logout back button should always direct to login page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security and this is the configuration file,

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/common.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <form-login 
            login-page="/login.htm" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true" 
            default-target-url="/loginPlease.htm"/>

    <logout 
            invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/login.htm" 
            logout-url="/logout.htm"/>

    <session-management >
           <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
                     error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"
                     expired-url="/login.htm"/>
       </session-management>
```

After logging out if a person enters back button he is redirected to the last page, but I want him to be always redirected to the login page. This problem also arises if the user directly enters the link in the browser, even if he has logged out, he is redirected to that page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" filters="none"/>
```

which prevents execution of the SessionManagementFilter, as well as every other one. This also means  and  tags won't work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't help. I'm trying to develop in such a way that I hide the confidential pages. This even by entering back button, the page wont display.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of your problem (having people remain logged out when going back after logging out VS. having people remain logged in when going back after logging in) [was solved by putting in a cache-management filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249888/how-to-handle-back-browser-button-problem-using-spring).

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```