# Redirect to login page on browse back

Tags: spring-mvc

I have scenario where user submits login form with post method and gets login success page. After that user logs out and clicks on back button. The browser loads login success page page from cache.
But my requirement is when user clicks on browser back button i should redirect to login page.

I am using Spring mvc and jsp. Please suggest me best way to handle this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Lakshmipathi.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249888/how-to-handle-back-browser-button-problem-using-spring.

Comment: Hi Deinum, Thanks for the reply. It is working for the GET request but not for post request.

Comment: Define it isn't working, there shouldn't be a difference. Have you used a filter or interceptor?

Comment: I used filter only. When use that it is clearing the response but user can submit the old form with refresh.

Comment: Well of course because that is what the previous request was. The POST will be submitted again. But that is a whole different issue...

Comment: I have seen a design pattern Post Redirect Get. Can you please suggest me is it good practice to use the above pattern?

Comment: Yes it is. But I also would assume that your POST requests are protected, so even the POST should redirect to your login page (after which, depending on the configuration, the POST will be handled).